# ffftp ホストの設定に関して

Tags: ftp

webサイト作成のためApache24とFFFTPを使っています。

FFFTPのホスト設定の際にホスト名はApache24のhttpd.confに記載してあったのですが、パスワードとユーザー名がどこに記載してあるかわかりません。どこに記載してあるのでしょうか。
初心者で分からないことだらけなのでご享受ください

Comment: apacheはどこにインストールしているのでしょうか？ご自身の開発しているPCのローカル？もしくは、レンタルサーバなどの借りている環境？もしくは仮想環境？

Comment: そもそもApacheをインストールしただけでは、FTPでの接続はできません。FTPで接続できるようにするには、サーバーにPure-FTPdやVSFTPといったFTP用のソフトウェアをインストールする必要がありますが、その手のソフトウェアは何かインストールされていますか？

Answer (score 0):

- Apache はHTMLなどをWeb上に公開するための **Webサーバ** です。
- 一方で FFFTP はFTPサーバとデータのやり取りを行うための **FTPクライアント** です。

FFFTPでサーバに接続するのはあくまでデータを置くためであって、Apache と直接の関連はありません。

参照しているデータは同じでも、コンテンツを公開するための下準備として「FTPでデータを転送する」のと、実際に「Apacheがコンテンツを公開」してブラウザで内容を表示するのでは通信の方式が違います。

FTPで接続するためには **FTPのアカウント情報** が必要となりますが、特にパスワードが平文(直接読める状態)で保存されていることはまずありません。

詳しくは接続先のサーバを管理している人に確認してみてください。